# Fabric.js how to clip by image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, mask

The title say it all. You can see [Fabric.js Mask Filter Demo](http://resources.aleph-1.com/mask/). This should be pretty simple but I can't find any example of applying mask to Fabric.js.

I am trying to apply mask to my JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/342/

From my JSFiddle, my goal is to have both `logo` and `pugImg` clipped inside [this picture](http://campratty.com/1faq/faqimage1/mask7b.jpg) (or any picture if you want). Well, I can't even mask one picture anyway, so if this is not bothering you, please update the JSFiddle for better explanation.

In addition, the code from @kangax, creator of Fabric.js <3, [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816753/fabric-js-clip-canvas-or-object-group-to-polygon) should be the solution but I can't manage to work. The result should be like the image below. Any further suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You are not really trying ot mask an image. You are using some compositing effects.
There are a couple of things to understand that are not directly related to fabric.js.

A mask goes over an image.

The demo link you posted will not make you get the effect as in the screenshot.

If this is the case, you should have:

- a light blue canvas
- a pug.jpg image
- a white `overlay image` with a girl-shaped transparent hole in it

Make a sandwich with those 3.
In this case you are `masking` the canvas not the image.

If you have a girl-shaped path, you can clip the canvas as seen in:

[Fabric.js Clip Canvas (or object group) To Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816753/fabric-js-clip-canvas-or-object-group-to-polygon)

But you state that you want to use a image instead.
So if you do not have the overlay with girl-shaped hole, you can use another solution to get the same effect:

- a transparent canvas
- a light blu image with a shape you need and transparent pixels all around
- a pug.jpg image

Add the first image on the canvas;
set the `globalCompositeOperation` of the pug.jpg to 'source-atop'
paint the other image over the other

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/2.svg', function(img){
  img1 = img;
  fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg', function(img){
    img1.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
    img2 = img;
    img2.scaleToHeight(300);
    img2.left = 50;
    img2.top = 50;
    img2.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
    canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.add(img2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script type ="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: how we can do it for text object same like text. Live inside it shape