# Clip to shape of image in fabric js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, clip

I was trying to implement like similar website.

http://printio.ru/full_print_tees/new

Even i tried answer of following post but it is not working.Does any one have the solution or fiddle.
[Fabric.js Clip Canvas (or object group) To Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816753/fabric-js-clip-canvas-or-object-group-to-polygon)

I have create following example but it is not working similar. Please let me know what is problem

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fabric.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border: 1px solid red; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        var group = [];

        fabric.loadSVGFromURL("http://fabricjs.com/assets/2.svg",function(objects,options) {

            var loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);

            loadedObjects.set({
                    left: 100,
                    top: 100

            });

            canvas.add(loadedObjects);
            shape = canvas.item(0);
            canvas.remove(shape);
            canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
              shape.render(ctx);
            };
            canvas.renderAll();

        },function(item, object) {
                object.set('id',item.getAttribute('id'));
                group.push(object);
        });



          }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to clip by IMAGE or by PATH?

Comment: i want to clip by image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463613/fabric-js-how-to-mask-an-image/35477758#35477758

Comment: but when i try with my svg it is not working. Actually when there is black background

Comment: Clipping by IMAGE is a way, clipping by SVG SHAPE is another. Clipping by image requires transparent background, clipping by shape not.

Answer (score 2):

Hello are you looking something like this on my example?

1. load one image (t-shirt)
2. add i-text object
3. manipulate text object (edit,move up/down/left/right) on the t-shirt

**small snippet:**

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(myImg, function(myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.scale(scaleFactor).set({ left: 0, top: 0 });

    var text = new fabric.Text('the_text_sample\nand more', {
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                fontSize:20,
            });

    text.set("top",myImg.height*scaleFactor-myImg.height*scaleFactor+150);
    text.set("left",myImg.width*scaleFactor/2-text.width/2);

    var group = new fabric.Group([ img1,text ], { left: 10, top: 10 });
    canvas.add(group);
console.log(canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].text);
});
```

live example : https://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/zrazuhcq/

[image]

Hope helps,good luck.